# How would I overlay an image in the center of an offset div?

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I want to be able to center some icons over a banner which is in the middle of a div that has been ofset. I can't use absolute positioning as it would center it but not ofset it. How would I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might `margin: auto;` work? Or do you need vertical centering as well?

EDIT:
Maybe something along the lines of:

```
<div>
  <div style="width:208px; height: 58px; margin: auto;">
    <img src="some_image_somewhere.png" width="208" height="58" style="position:absolute;">
    <img src="some_image_somewhere.png" width="208" height="58">
  </div>
</div>
```

This shows both images over one another centered in the top div, but it's not pretty (code-wise, imo).

Comment: This doesn't work, it it not on the image or in the center of the page and with absolute positioning it is still to the left of the div and just overlays the text beneath the image.

Comment: Well, margin doesn't seem to work, but giving the parent div `text-align: center;` does seem to.

Comment: Using a relative position centers it but how would I overlay the other image which is above it?

Comment: I thought of something else which _might_ work, I edited my answer for it

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to set both to an absolute position
2. the outter div needs to be relative
3. also the outter div should have a width set (this way when you specify a full width to the image's container, it will align it to the middle (because you set a text-align: center to the div you need centered)).
4. every image needs to be in its own div with an absolute position (the z order is as it is in the code, the one after will be on top).

code:

```
<div style="width:300px; height: 100px; position: relative;">
<div style="position: absolute;"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aBfM.png" width="300" height="100"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; text-align: center;"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH3Qw.png" width="100" height="100"></div></div>
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9PhP/

Answer (score 0):

jackJoe is right.

you can also use `style="position: absolute; top:10000px"` to adjust the height of the overlapping image.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is this answer really adding value to this question? The already accepted answer already demonstrates to use absolute positioning. Also, generally, if you know another answer to be correct (jackJoe's in your opinion) the correct way is to upvote that answer. As a new user you cannot yet comment or even upvote. However, duplicating existing info will not gain you reputation.